# how to write test bench for slave module in which it assign input values from master module?

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I have written two Verilog modules so called  master.v and slave.v in which master.v module provides output values and slave module is going to use these master's output values. Can you please advise me on how to write testbench for assigning Slave's input as master's output values?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're going to have to give us a bit more to go on.

Comment: In this case, master and slave need to connect using wires. Please provide your situation and question using a example.

Answer (score 0):

Take instance of Master.v and Slave.v in Testbench.v and connect respective wires(signals) and then drive necessary inputs like reset and clock to both master and slave instance if any. See below basic diagram.

[image]